# How to split a large file and execute a command on each split as it is finished

Tags: linux, bash, split

OS: LINUX

So I have a situation where I normally have gz files over 30 GB I split on 2GB using split and then push each split to S3.

Unfortunately now I run the split and then when it is finished I move each split in parallel.

I would like to split and as soon as the first part file is finished being written, execute the push command and do the same for each part file as it is finished. This would save me allot of time and lower the amount of time I am flooding the systems outgoing band.

Anyway I looked for --exec or something like it on split and it just does not exist. I can and will write a script to watch the split-to dir and act accordingly but I thought I would ask if anyone had a command that already does this that I just am unaware of.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You could employ a loop with dd

```
#gen a test file
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1K count=1024 of=test.bin
sourcefile="test.bin"
```

This should be easily scriptified (bash assumed):

```
bsize=$((128*1024))
flength=$(stat --printf=%s "$sourcefile")
for i in $(seq 0 $((($flength-1) / $bsize))); do dd if="$sourcefile" bs=$bsize skip=$i count=1 2>/dev/null; done | md5sum

# verify    
md5sum "$sourcefile"

for i in $(seq $RANDOM); do echo hello >> "$sourcefile"; done
flength=$(stat --printf=%s "$sourcefile")
for i in $(seq 0 $((($flength-1) / $bsize))); do dd if="$sourcefile" bs=$bsize skip=$i count=1 2>/dev/null; done | md5sum

# verify    
md5sum "$sourcefile"
```

On my system this worked like a charm, generating the following output

```
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB) copied, 0.27551 s, 3.8 MB/s
d73c5a920dae16861983c95d8fb1e94b  -
d73c5a920dae16861983c95d8fb1e94b  test.bin
d14ae9ae62652bc7768b076226a6320a  -
d14ae9ae62652bc7768b076226a6320a  test.bin
```

I will leave the challenge of piping the info to your network jobs to you for now.
Have a look at mkfifo, redirect each sub job to a separate fifo and perhaps use xargs -PN to split in parallel jobs if that is of any value (normally bandwith is the limiting factor).